# Are there problems of implementing HashSet using HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

In java HashSet is implemented using a HashMap. So when we add an item to the set the following code is executed.

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

what happens when two objects that are different but having equal hash is added to the HashSet; will it (HashSet) contain both the objects or what happens then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hashmap uses `.equals()` as well as `.hash()`.  two things are not the same unless `.equals()` returns true.  the same will be true of hashset.

so if two objects are distinct but have the same hash, they will both be stored, and both available, because `.equals()` will still return `false`.

it's true that, internally, the hash is used to decide where to store the objects, but multiple objects with the same hash can still be stored (there's a slight performance penalty because it gets more complicated, but that's all).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a hashmap will contain both elements. I can't find the specific method that it uses, but popular methods of dealing with collisions include using a linked list for each bucket, or just sticking elements in nearby empty buckets.

Comment: Java's implementation of HashMap indeed uses linked list style structures (internally called Entry) to represent a bucket. The following expression is used to determine the bucket for a given key:  hashcode & (numBuckets-1).   Once that's done, the keys in the bucket are checked using .equals(), and the element is either replaced or added to that bucket.