# Which data structure used by HashSet?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have seen internal data structure used by hashset is HashTable on many websites but when i saw HashSet.class (after decompile) it is using HashMap.Now iam confused please clear my confusion.HashSet uses which data structure ?

Also tell me internal data structure used by linkedhashset, treeset, hashmap, hashtable, linkedhashmap, treemap.

Comment: Go look at the source code.

Comment: Yes, a `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`.  [The Javadoc even says so.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)  You should peruse the Javadoc for these classes; it would answer most of these questions.

Comment: @GeorgeNetu:  No, I don't see that as a duplicate question at all.

Comment: @Makoto I would agree that the *question* is, but the "I mean implementation wise.....?" in the question is ignored in most every answer so .. I don't think it's a "suitable" duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431581/why-do-set-data-structures-in-java-use-map-internally?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217414/what-is-the-main-difference-between-hashset-treeset-and-linkedhashset-hashmap?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680751/are-there-problems-of-implementing-hashset-using-hashmap?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` internally stores values as part of `HashMap`'s key and it puts a dummy value as value

[Check the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29), relevant portions extracted:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

public boolean add(E e) { 
 return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but it barely feels like an answer.

Comment: @Makoto Such is the problem with such questions :|